# What is the logic behind multiexp method in bulletproof Monero implementation

Tags: ringct, ring-signatures, bulletproofs

Could anybody explain the logic behind `multiexp` method in the bulletproof Monero implementation.

Source code: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/v0.17.1.9/src/ringct/bulletproofs.cc#L85-L94

Answer (score 1):

The function is performing Multi-Exponentiation and is just a stub for using the most efficient algorithm (Straus or Pippenger, cached or uncached), based on the input data.

Some timings in [this commit](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/263431c486bcaddf442c912cf56171a778322316/src/ringct/multiexp.cc#L51-L80), which have informed selection criteria.